# Java EE - Seam 2 vs Seam 3 - which should I choose now?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, seam, seam2, seam3

I'm starting new enterprise application. I've choosen the following technologies: jee6 (jsf + primefaces, ejb) and hibernate. I'll deploy on Glassfish 3.

Question is which Seam version should I choose? I know Seam 3 is the newest, but Seam 2 seems as it is being developed too. I quickly ran through Seam 2 and 3 docs, and Seam 2 looks much easier to me (especially security module)

Comment: Neither - they're both terrible.

Comment: So what else do you propose to speed up development? Seam 3 faces module looks really nice for me.

Comment: Web services, preferrably REST, talking to whatever UI that can make an HTTP connection and send a request: mobile, HTML 5, etc.  If Seam and Faces look so good to you, why are you asking here?  Voting to close.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If choosing between Seam 2 and Seam 3.

I would recomend going with Seam 2, and it is still being developed on, it will soon as I understand be releasing Seam 2.3 with support for JSF2, JBoss AS 7.1, etc...

Seam 2 is more productive and as you said easier to work with at the moment. How it will be after DeltaSpike is up and running might be another story.

I have also read they are considering to rename Seam 2.3 to Seam 4.

It is Seam 3 that is moving to DeltaSpike.

/Trind

Comment: That's really nice, have you tried 2.3.0.Beta2? Does it support jee6? Any ideas when stable version will be out?

Comment: Yeah i have tried Seam 2.3, and it works fine, some minor bugs.  It should support jee 6 but it has a few bug that are gonna be fixed in CR1(next version). https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBSEAM/fixforversion/12316770. However there are quite a few changes so it will take some time i you are gonna migrate from 2.2 to 2.3

Comment: There is no talk about renaming Seam 2.3 to Seam 4, not sure where you heard that one.

Comment: If you're starting a new application, use Java EE 6. If you don't find what need their either look at creating your own extensions or some of the other ones that are out there like Seam 3, MyFaces CODI, etc.

Comment: Well maby it wern't the best source about it that it should be renamaed to seam 4: https://community.jboss.org/message/714690#714690

Answer (score 3):

Seam 2 is a dead road, the project now is donated to the Apache Foundation ans it's called DeltaSpike.

IMHO the best way is to use the standart, and J2EE 6 has almost everything that you need.
There are several alternatives for security, you can try picketlink http://www.jboss.org/picketlink

Comment: That's Seam 3, Seam 2.x is certainly not a dead road. DeltaSpike will be the place for your CDI extensions based on the extension capabilities of CDI.

Comment: Sorry but for me...all these old fashioned frameworks are dead. http://slidesha.re/wS2zwu Just saying...

Comment: You're comparing different things than what the OP was. You're talking mainly about front end frameworks where I was talking about backend frameworks. Ultimately the choice is yours and do what makes sense for you and your team. Java EE 6 (including extensions via CDI) makes a very good backend approach. For frontend, that all depends.

Comment: I'm not comparing anything, where did I mention frontend?

Comment: The presentation you linked compared mostly frontend specific frameworks.

Answer (score 1):

Seam 3 is still lacking in lots of simple basics, whilst the overall patterns are perhaps better than Seam 2, I'm getting quite frustrated trying to do stuff that Seam 2 can do out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

Seam 3 or seam 2 is not a valid question imo. What you should ask yourself is if you want cdi or seam 2. The answer is you want cdi. With that you get a multitude of benefits. They partly follow with using the standard in java ee. Especially when the spec was led by Gavin King and takes the best from seam 2, spring and other frameworks. You should actually read the whole jsr-299 spec it is really informative. Other huge benefits is all the great extensions and great stuff in the pipe like deltaspike.

I think it's obvious how much more promise cdi has. Seam 3 is nothing but some extra seasoning, while it can make the diffrence it is not what you should compare seam 2 with. There is no equivalent for extensions like seam 3 in seam 2. Seam 2 is not built to be that easy to extend.